# .net Framework installation using Advanced Installer

Tags: .net, installation, .net-framework-version, advanced-installer

I added the **.net framework prerequisite to my installer using Advanced Installer** which I had set to framework 4.5.My System already has framework 4.5 installed,It still forces me to install framework 4.5.**I want that if the framework is already installed,it should skip the framework installation and proceed to the main installation**.How is it to be done?

Please Help,

Thanks

Comment: This isn't really programming related, but AI prerequisites are supposed to work that way.  You may have a buggy version of AI...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All *.NET Framework* prerequisites were updated in [Advanced Installer 10.8](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/release-10.8.html). More specifically, *.NET Framework 4.x* **cannot** be installed on Windows 8/Server 2012 (or later) using the redistributable prerequisite but you can enable them from Windows Features.

Cheers

Comment: That information was helpful Thanks :)